# Clang IntelliSense locks up the keyboard

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, gdb, clang

I'm trying out the trial version for the Visual Studio add on VisualGDB to test some Linux cross compilation. In that package the Clang IntelliSense was included and it's basically stopping me from writing any code.

For example when I try to include something I type '#' and the IntelliSense gives me suggestions. However I can't keep typing and I can't select any of the suggestions with enter or with my mouse. The only thing I can do is hit backspace or click with the mouse outside and repeat while typing one letter at a time. It looks like this:
[image]

As you understand it's impossible to work like this. I haven't found anyone with similar problems and I can't even find how to disable it in Visual Studio.

I'm also getting loads of errors in the Clang IntelliSense Diagnostics Console like this every type I press a key on the keyboard:

```
[+0:00:19.511] Method not found: 'Boolean Sysprogs.LanguageServices.Interfaces.IUniversalDeclarationCollection.PerformCustomFinalCommit(Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextManager.Interop.IVsTextView, System.String, Int32, Int32, Char)'. while trying to handle character event in the completion form
[+0:00:19.511] Stack trace:
[+0:00:19.511]     at Sysprogs.LanguageServices.CompletionSetImpl.OnCommit(String textSoFar, Int32 index, Int32 selected, UInt16 commitChar, String& completeWord)
[+0:00:19.511]     at aoc.a.a(Char A_0, Int32 A_1, Boolean A_2, Boolean& A_3, Boolean& A_4)
[+0:00:19.667] Method not found: 'Boolean Sysprogs.LanguageServices.Interfaces.IUniversalDeclarationCollection.PerformCustomFinalCommit(Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextManager.Interop.IVsTextView, System.String, Int32, Int32, Char)'. while trying to handle character event in the completion form
[+0:00:19.667] Stack trace:
[+0:00:19.667]     at Sysprogs.LanguageServices.CompletionSetImpl.OnCommit(String textSoFar, Int32 index, Int32 selected, UInt16 commitChar, String& completeWord)
[+0:00:19.667]     at aoc.a.a(Char A_0, Int32 A_1, Boolean A_2, Boolean& A_3, Boolean& A_4)
```

**EDIT** I managed to change the IntelliSense engine in the Clang IntelliSense Diagnostics Console to use Visual C++ IntelliSense so now I can at least continue to work. It would still be nice to get the Clang one working since I assume there is a reason why it was included in the VisualGDB installation.

Answer (score 0):

It is under Tools/Options, Text Editor.

[image]

Comment: Isn't that just the normal Visual Studio IntelliSense?

Comment: Yes.  I'm pretty sure that's where it is disabled for anything.

Comment: Ok, but I would still like to have at least the normal IntelliSense. And I found that I could change the engine used in the Clan IntelliSense Diagnostics Console so now I can at least work. It still would be nice to use the Clang one since I guess there is a reason why it was included in the installation of VisualGDB.